# Generate Dynamic table from array / array multidimensional with rowspans

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hei guys! I want to create a table with tr's using data from array or multidimensional array.

My arrays are dynamics, it can look like:

```
{
    "FIRST TD IN FIRST TR -> tr rowspan=1": [
        {
            "name -> second td in first tr": "x",
            "title -> third td in first tr": "y",
            "email -> fourth td in first tr": "z",
            "phone -> fifth td in first tr": "0"
        }
    ],
    "FIRST TD IN SECOND TR -> tr rowspan=1": [
        {
            "name -> second td in second tr": "x",
            "title -> third td in second tr": "y",
            "email -> fourth td in second tr": "z",
            "phone -> fifth td in second tr": "0"
        }
    ],
    "FIRST TD IN THIRD TR -> tr rowspan=2": [
        {
            "name -> second td in third tr": "x",
            "title -> third td in third tr": "y",
            "email -> fourth td in third tr": "z",
            "phone -> fifth td in third tr": "0"
        },
        {
            "name -> second td in fourth tr": "x",
            "title -> third td in fourth tr": "y",
            "email -> fourth td in fourth tr": "z",
            "phone -> fifth td in fourth tr": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Another one it can look like this:

```
{
    "FIRST TD IN FIRST TR -> rowspan 2": {
        "SECOND TD IN FIRST TR -> rowspan 1": [
            {
                "name -> third td in first tr": "x",
                "title -> fourth td in first tr": "y",
                "email -> fifth td in first tr": "z",
                "phone -> sixth td in first tr": "0"
            }
        ],
        "FIRST TD IN SECOND TR -> indented because of parent tr rowspan": [
            {
                "name -> second td in second tr": "x",
                "title -> third td in second tr": "y",
                "email -> fourth td in second tr": "z",
                "phone -> fifth td in second tr": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    "FIRST TD IN THIRD TR -> rowspan 2": {
        "SECOND TD IN THIRD TR -> rowspan 1": [
            {
                "name -> third td in third tr": "x",
                "title -> fourth td in third tr": "y",
                "email -> fifth td in third tr": "z",
                "phone -> sixth td in third tr": "0"
            }
        ],
        "FIRST TD IN FOURTH TR -> indented because of parent tr rowspan": [
            {
                "name -> second td in fourth tr": "x",
                "title -> third td in fourth tr": "y",
                "email -> fourth td in fourth tr": "z",
                "phone -> fifth td in fourth tr": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    "FIRST TD IN FIFTH TR -> rowspan 1": {
        "SECOND TD IN FIFTH TR -> rowspan 1": [
            {
                "name -> third td in fifth tr": "x",
                "title -> fourth td in fifth tr": "y",
                "email -> fifth td in fifth tr": "z",
                "phone -> sixth td in fifth tr": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    "FIRST TD IN SIXTH TR -> rowspan 3": {
        "SECOND TD IN SIXTH TR -> rowspan 2": [
            {
                "name -> third td in SIXTH tr": "x",
                "title -> fourth td in SIXTH tr": "y",
                "email -> fifth td in SIXTH tr": "z",
                "phone -> sixth td in SIXTH tr": "0"
            },
            ----> next one indented because of parent rowspan (2)
            {
                "name -> third td in seventh tr": "x",
                "title -> fourth td in seventh tr": "y",
                "email -> fifth td in seventh tr": "z",
                "phone -> sixth td in seventh tr": "0"
            }
        ],
        "SECOND TD IN EIGHT TR -> rowspan 1": [
            {
                "name -> third td in EIGHT tr": "x",
                "title -> fourth td in EIGHT tr": "y",
                "email -> fifth td in EIGHT tr": "z",
                "phone -> sixth td in EIGHT tr": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The point is, the arrays can be on two levels or, on 3 levels.

**My code:**

```
$duplicate_keys = array();
    $country_multiple_rows = false;
    $first_row_has_m_row = 1;
    $middle_row_multiple = 0;
    $skip_first_row = 0;

    // find nr of rows
    foreach($array as $index => $result){
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        // IF TABLE IS ON 3 LEVELS //
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        if(isAssoc($result)){
            // COMPARED COUNTRIES
            foreach($result as $head => $content){
                if(isset($head)){
                    $duplicate_keys[$index][$head] = count($result[$head]);
                }
            }

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // if VAT CONTACT PERSON AND COUNTRY HAS MANY ENTRIES
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if(count($result) > 1){
                $data .= "<tr class='initial_row'>";
                    foreach($result as $vk => $vv){
                        // get department row_height
                        foreach($duplicate_keys[$index] as $country_index => $country_rows){
                            $multiple_countries_in_department += $country_rows;
                        }

                        if($multiple_countries_in_department > 1){
                            // vat department with multiple rows
                            $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $multiple_countries_in_department . "'>" . $index . "</td>";
                        }else{
                            // vat department
                            $data .= "<td>" . $index . "</td>";
                        }

                        $vat_department = $index;
                        $country_of_department = $vk;

                        if($duplicate_keys[$vat_department][$country_of_department] > 1){
                            $first_row_has_m_row += 1;
                        }

                        // table only first row
                        foreach($vv[0] as $i => $v){
                            if($duplicate_keys[$vat_department][$country_of_department] > 1 && $v === $country_of_department){
                                $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $duplicate_keys[$vat_department][$country_of_department] . "'>" . $v . "</td>";
                            }else{
                                $data .= "<td>" . $v . "</td>";
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                $data .= "</tr>";

                // list other values
                $keys = array_keys($array[$vat_department]);
                if($first_row_has_m_row > 1){
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($array[$vat_department]); $i++){
                        $data .= "<tr class='rest_of_initial_row'>";
                            if(count($array[$vat_department][$keys[$i]]) > 1){
                                foreach($array[$vat_department][$keys[$i]][0] as $q => $w){
                                    if ($w === $keys[$i]){
                                        $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $duplicate_keys[$vat_department][$w] . "'>" . $w . "</td>";
                                    }else{
                                        $data .= "<td>" . $w . "</td>";
                                    }

                                    $department = $vat_department;
                                    $department_country = $keys[$i];
                                    $last_row_multiple++;
                                }
                            }else{
                                foreach($array[$vat_department][$keys[$i]] as $index => $value){
                                    foreach($value as $j => $l){
                                        if ($l === $keys[$i] && $duplicate_keys[$vat_department][$l] > 1){
                                            $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $duplicate_keys[$vat_department][$l] . "'>" . $l . "</td>";
                                        }else{
                                            $data .= "<td>" . $l . "</td>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                            // if(is_array($array[$vat_department][$keys[$i]])){
                            //  foreach($array[$vat_department][$keys[$i]] as $index => $value){
                            //      // skip first value as it is defined above
                            //      if ($skip_first_row++ === 0) continue;

                            //      foreach($value as $j => $l){
                            //          if($country_of_department !== $l){
                            //              $data .= "<td>" . $l . "</td>";
                            //          }
                            //      }
                            //  }
                            // }
                        $data .= "</tr>";
                    }
                }else{
                    $keys = array_keys($array[$vat_department]);
                    for($i = 1; $i < count($array[$vat_department]); $i++){
                        $data .= "<tr class='secondary_row'>";
                            if(count($array[$vat_department][$keys[$i]]) > 1){
                                foreach($array[$vat_department][$keys[$i]][0] as $q => $w){
                                    if ($w === $keys[$i]){
                                        $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $duplicate_keys[$vat_department][$w] . "'>" . $w . "</td>";
                                    }else{
                                        $data .= "<td>" . $w . "</td>";
                                    }

                                    $department = $vat_department;
                                    $department_country = $keys[$i];
                                    $middle_row_multiple++;
                                }
                            }else{
                                foreach($array[$vat_department][$keys[$i]] as $index => $value){
                                    foreach($value as $j => $l){
                                        if ($l === $keys[$i] && $duplicate_keys[$vat_department][$l] > 1){
                                            $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $duplicate_keys[$vat_department][$l] . "'>" . $l . "</td>";
                                        }else{
                                            $data .= "<td>" . $l . "</td>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        $data .= "</tr>";
                    }

                    if($array[$department][$department_country]){
                        if($last_row_multiple !== 0){
                            for($j = 0; $j < count($array[$department][$department_country]); $j++){
                                $data .= "<tr class='rest_of_secondary_rows'>";                                 
                                    foreach($array[$department][$department_country][$j] as $q => $w){
                                        if ($w !== $department_country){
                                            $data .= "<td>" . $w . "</td>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                $data .= "</tr>";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($array[$department][$department_country]){
                        if($middle_row_multiple !== 0){
                            for($j = 1; $j < count($array[$department][$department_country]); $j++){
                                $data .= "<tr class='rest_of_secondary_rows'>";                                 
                                    foreach($array[$department][$department_country][$j] as $q => $w){
                                        if ($w !== $department_country){
                                            $data .= "<td>" . $w . "</td>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                $data .= "</tr>";
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }

                $multiple_countries_in_department = 0;
                $first_row_has_m_row = 1;
                $middle_row_multiple = 0;
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            // if VAT CONTACT PERSON HAS SINGLE ENTRY
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            }else{
                $data .= "<tr>";
                    foreach($result as $rk => $rv){
                        // create left headers
                        foreach($duplicate_keys[$index] as $dk => $dv){
                            $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $dv . "'>" . $index . "</td>";

                            // if country has multiple values
                            if($dv > 1){
                                $country_multiple_rows = true;
                                $row_height = $duplicate_keys[$index][$rk];
                                $country_duplicate_name = $rk;

                                // identify COUNTRY
                                foreach($rv[0] as $h => $v){
                                    // if name is equal to loop item
                                    if($v === $rk){
                                        $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $duplicate_keys[$index][$rk] . "'>" . $v . "</td>";
                                    // other country contact details
                                    }else{
                                        $data .= "<td>" . $v . "</td>";
                                    }
                                }

                                break 2;
                            }else{
                                foreach($rv as $h => $v){
                                    foreach($v as $vh => $vv){
                                        $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $duplicate_keys[$index][$rk] . "'>" . $vv . "</td>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                $data .= "</tr>";

                if($country_multiple_rows){
                    // 2nd++ row of country
                    for($i = 1; $i < $row_height; $i++){
                        $data .= "<tr>";
                            foreach($array[$index][$country_duplicate_name][$i] as $ih => $iv){
                                if($iv !== $country_duplicate_name){
                                    $data .= "<td>" . $iv . "</td>";
                                }
                            }
                        $data .= "</tr>";
                    }
                }
                $country_multiple_rows = false;
            }

        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        // IF TABLE IS ON 2 LEVELS //
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        }else{
            ////////////////
            // NO COMPARE //
            ////////////////
            $duplicate_keys[$index] = count($result);

            /////////////////////////////////////////
            // if VAT CONTACT PERSON HAS MANY ENTRIES
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            if(count($result) > 1){
                $data .= "<tr>";
                    foreach($result as $vk => $vv){
                        // table left header
                        $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $duplicate_keys[$index] . "'>" . $index . "</td>";

                        // table only first row
                        foreach($result[0] as $i => $v){
                            $data .= "<td>" . $v . "</td>";
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                $data .= "</tr>";

                // list other values
                for($i = 1; $i < count($result); $i++){
                    $data .= "<tr>";
                        foreach($result[$i] as $index => $value){
                            $data .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
                        }
                    $data .= "</tr>";
                }
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            // if VAT CONTACT PERSON HAS SINGLE ENTRY
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            }else{
                $data .= "<tr>";
                    foreach($result as $rk => $rv){
                        // create left headers
                        $data .= "<td " . $type . "='" . $duplicate_keys[$index] . "'>" . $index . "</td>";

                        foreach($rv as $h => $v){
                            // show data
                            $data .= "<td>" . $v . "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                $data .= "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Using my code it wrecks the table layout as it doesnt create the new tr's when it needs to be created or it keeps the loop and add more tds in a single tr that should split in more tr's.

**This is how it should look like:**
https://prnt.sc/qt8s5t

And a more complex one:
https://prnt.sc/qt8rk6

Not the ones from the example arrays but you'll get the point.

Comment: Is that input data format a given? Because that is rather terrible to begin with, for what you want. What you _should_ have here, is simply a “full” data array with the complete data for each row - such as one would typically get it from a database. That then needs to be ordered accordingly, and then you implement a _control break_ to get the data output in the desired format. […]

Comment: […] Simply creating a full table, and leaving table cells with a repeating value empty would be a bit easier; but counting the number of repeating values and creating the proper rowspan value “retroactively” should also be possible, using a bit of trickery. If that gets too complicated for your taste, it can also be done by looping over the array twice, getting the necessary rowspan counts first, and creating the output second.